# Heuristic function for estimating nurikabe puzzle state

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, algorithm

I am trying to write a program for solving nurikabe puzzle. I need a method to approximately **represent the state of the game in one number**, to choose the best way for the algorithm to continue. I can't seem to find any obvious link between solutions of different nurikabe boards, thus no way to estimate how far the current state is from the final one. I thought about manhattan distance between islands, density of islands etc.

Comment: By representing the state of the game with a single number, do you mean that number would be lower or higher based on how close it is to being solved? Like a score?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have meant.

Comment: This sounds like a question about devising a scoring function to use for *solving a Nurikabe puzzle through stochastic search methods*. One example of this method is [Solving Nurikabe with Ant Colony Optimization](https://nrl.northumbria.ac.uk/id/eprint/39017/1/Amos%20et%20al%20-%20Solving%20Nurikabe%20with%20Ant%20Colony%20Optimization%20AAM.pdf) by Amos et al. Briefly, the solution begins with a completely black grid, and after running the ant colony algorithm the solutions are scored according to the number of times the rules of Nurikabe were broken ("constraints broken").

Comment: While coming up with such an algorithm is arguably a puzzle itself, this question might be better suited for [CompSci SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)